# Фоновый поток для recycler.setAdapter

Tags: android, многопоточность

Как правильно отправить установку адаптера в фоновый поток так, чтобы пользователь во время загрузки мог взаимодействовать с приложением? На данный момент ни на один клик приложение не реагирует до полной загрузки адаптера.
Так же подойдет и отправка загрузки фрагмента в поток – разницы, думаю, не будет.

*Взаимодействие нужно и в активити, а ресайклер находится во фрагменте.

Comment: `setAdapter` - это UI-операция и переносить её в фон скорее всего вообще запрещено. Вы уверены что проблема именно в этом вызове а не загрузке/подготовке данных для адаптера? Обычно адаптер изначально создают пустым (без данных) и прикрепляют к ресайклеру сразу при инициализации вьюшек, а после загрузки/подготовки данных их добавляют в уже существующий адаптер.

Comment: @woesss Да, уверен, что проблема в установке. Для этого сделал создание адаптера во время запуска приложения. Во фрагменте только его установка – он просто достаточно большой. 
А подготовку фрагмента (fm.replace(...)) тоже запрещено в фон кидать ?

Comment: Кажется, вы что-то не то и/или не так делаете. Покажите код адаптера - возможно, у вас в onCreate/onBindViewHolder какая-то сложная работа на главном потоке происходит (чтение/запись в файл, например). Скорее всего, её можно оттуда убрать и всё будет работать быстро.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Как я и сказал, он достаточно большой - 100+ объектов, в которые устанавливается картинка и 1-3 текста (При наличии). И, за исключением всего нескольких из них, в каждом есть еще один Recycler, в нём 1-4 объекта, в которых всегда картинка и 2 текста. Может проблема всё-таки в размере? Или все равно есть вариант, что это я где-то что-то делаю не так?

Comment: Попробуйте временно убрать внутренние RecyclerView - будет ли прирост скорости? Если да - попробуйте там посмотреть что не так. Возможно, вы картинки как-то не так отображаете? Пользуетесь библиотеками типа Glide для них? Не видя код - сложно что-то конкретное сказать.